# C++ Illegal else

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, compiler-errors

Okay, I want to make a simple IPO Loop that asks for Fahrenheit or Celsius conversion, and then converts the users input based on their choice. I think I've got it, but My else clause messes up. I cant figure it out, and after looking at it for so long, maybe fresh eyes could more easily point out my mistake?

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int _tmain()
{
    int choice;
    double fahr, cel;

        cout << "Please choose 1 for fahrenheit, or 2 for Celsius: ";
        if (cin >> choice) {
            while (cin >> choice){
                if (choice == 1)
                    cout << "Enter Fahrenheit degrees to be        converted: " << endl;
                cin >> fahr;
                cel = (fahr - 32.0) / 1.8;
                cout << cel << " degrees" << endl;
                if(choice == 2)
                    cout << "Enter Celsius degrees to be converted: " << endl;
                cin >> cel;
                fahr = 9.0 / 5.0 * cel + 32.0;
                cout << fahr << " degrees" << endl;
                else {
                    cout << "Not a valid option";
                }
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a pair of curly braces between `if` and `else`.

Comment: "I think I've got it, but My else clause messes up."  And the problem is ... what, exactly?  How does it "mess up"?  Compiler error?  Results other than expected?  What's the expected result?

Comment: Well I feel pretty stupid. . . That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add braces `{}` when needed to define a code scope.

Like this:

```
if (choice == 1)
{
    cout << "Enter Fahrenheit degrees to be        converted: " << endl;
    cin >> fahr;
    cel = (fahr - 32.0) / 1.8;
    cout << cel << " degrees" << endl;
}
if(choice == 2)
{
    cout << "Enter Celsius degrees to be converted: " << endl;
    cin >> cel;
    fahr = 9.0 / 5.0 * cel + 32.0;
    cout << fahr << " degrees" << endl;
}
else 
{
    cout << "Not a valid option";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put curly braces around your if's:

```
if (choice == 1){
            cout << "Enter Fahrenheit degrees to be        converted: " << endl;
            cin >> fahr;
            cel = (fahr - 32.0) / 1.8;
            cout << cel << " degrees" << endl;
}
else if(choice == 2){
            cout << "Enter Celsius degrees to be converted: " << endl;
            cin >> cel;
            fahr = 9.0 / 5.0 * cel + 32.0;
            cout << fahr << " degrees" << endl;
}
else {
            cout << "Not a valid option";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things:
1. Use brace brackets to enclose all statements that should be executed for each if condition. This will clarify the scope of that if statement.
2. Change the second if to use else if, assuming that you expect user to enter either option 1 or 2 but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the brackets in the two `if`s. When `if` is encountered it only executes the `cout` statement. If you want it to execute more than one statement you should add curly braces `{}`